# Add buttons from inside button delegates in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I'm trying to learn a bit about building pages with C# and there's something that I REALLY don't get.
I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    UpdatePanel mainContainer = new UpdatePanel();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label someText = new Label();
        someText.Text = "text";
        LinkButton someLink = new LinkButton();
        someLink.Text = "first link";
        someLink.Click += delegate {
            Label someText2 = new Label();
            someText2.Text = "text2";
            LinkButton someLink2 = new LinkButton();
            someLink2.Text = "second link";
            someLink2.Click += delegate {

                Label someText3 = new Label();
                someText3.Text = "text3";
                LinkButton someLink3 = new LinkButton();
                someLink3.Text = "third link";
                mainContainer.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(someText3);
                mainContainer.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(someLink3);

            };
            mainContainer.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(someText2);
            mainContainer.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(someLink2);

        };


        form1.Controls.Add(mainContainer);
        mainContainer.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(someText);
        mainContainer.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(someLink);
    }
}
```

All in all, it should give something very simple, an UpdatePanel acting as a wrapper that contains: a "text" string followed by a "first link" link and the click on the "first link" should append another string and another link next to the initial ones. In turn, this second link should add a new third string and a new third link. However, a click on the second link only causes the removal of both the second text and the second link from the DOM. I can't even have a breakpoint inside the delegate for the second link. I have honestly no idea why this is happening. Any ideas?

My intention is to keep adding html objects to the site based on the clicks on programmatically added objects, is this not pissible?

Comment: Sorry - ASP.NET is no winforms :) the control tree has to be recreated after every single postback.

Comment: the control tree has to be recreated? Do I need to add new elements in new UpdatePannels?

Comment: Yes - ASP.NET remember's just what it gets from http POST request - i.e form fields, cookies, and query string parameters. One particulary interesting form field is ViewState - which you can use for persisting state. Control tree (all dynamically added controls) are in postback in the same state as in first request - unless you recreate them based on some information (typically ViewState).

Comment: So, example, if I want a menu that links to multiple pages without reloading I would need to have a variable in the ViewState that says which page to create. I can't just wipe the contents of the UpdatePanel and build the page. It seems... patchy. Is there a better way?

Comment: Best approach is to create menu inside update panel (static - no dynamic stuff - you can use databinding though), and add there a placeholder control as well. Into the placeholder load control based on clicked menu link; clicked link has to be persisted in viewstate as well (so the postback from the control inside placeholder will work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To better materialize the idea:

Suppose you have two controls Controls/Control1.ascx and Controls/Control2.ascx

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="PressMe 1" OnClick="ChangePage_Click" CausesValidation="false" CommandArgument="~/Controls/Control1.ascx" />
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="PressMe 2" OnClick="ChangePage_Click" CausesValidation="false" CommandArgument="~/Controls/Control2.ascx" />
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="placeholder" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (IsPostBack && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ActiveControl)) {
    placeholder.Controls.Clear();
    placeholder.Controls.Add(LoadControl(ActiveControl));
  }
}

protected string ActiveControl {
  get { return (string)ViewState["ActiveControl"]; }
  set { ViewState["ActiveControl"] = value; }
}

protected void ChangePage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var control = (IButtonControl)sender;
  ActiveControl = control.CommandArgument;
  placeholder.Controls.Clear();
  placeholder.Controls.Add(LoadControl(control.CommandArgument));
}
```

Comment: Wow that Placeholder did the trick nicely, tysm I had been fighting with this for a while